# Кто нибудь устанавливал YONA CMS, столкнулся с такой проблемой

Tags: php, cms, phalcon

Админка работает нормально, за исключением дерева категорий, перекидывает на фронтенд почему то, а вот фронтенд

Вот похоже совет к этой теме, но я не понял что нужно сделать =) phalcon стоит на Openserver
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588697/phalcon-assets-exception-non-free-csssminifier-not-available

```
Phalcon\Assets\Exception: Non-free jsminifier not available
#1  Phalcon\Assets\Manager->output(Object(Phalcon\Assets\Collection), Array([0] => Phalcon\Tag, [1] => javascriptInclude), js)
#2  Phalcon\Assets\Manager->outputJs(js)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поставил Openserver  последний, выставил в настройках последнюю версию php и apache  все заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По вашей ссылке пишут, что надо пересобрать библиотеку phalcon.so c параметром --without-non-free .

Но это для *nix-ов решение, а самое простое для виндовс - использовать другую версию Phalcon. Вероятно с более новой версией OpenServer шла новая версия Phalcon/